# Databinding progress bar Value and Maximum in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, progress-bar

I'm trying to implement a progress bar to monitor the downloading of content in a HttpWebRequest. I have never done databinding with XAML before, can anyone please give me tips on how I can set the Maximum value of the progress bar to the file size and the Value to the size of the content downloaded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This XAML:

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding DownloadProgress, Mode=OneWay}" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding DownloadSize, Mode=OneWay}" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
```

should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/229450.aspx/1/10) SL bug however. Make sure Maximum binding appears before the Value binding in the XAML.